How to implement lock-free slice append using CAS in Golang?
again edit:
This is my newest implement code.
The previous code has a race condition when using 'append'.
https://go.dev/play/p/YlJQbnHnhPp
func (group *Actions) Add(key string, action func()) {
    for {
        value, loaded := group.store.Load(key)
        if !loaded {
            actions := []func(){action}
            value, loaded = group.store.LoadOrStore(key, &actions)
            if !loaded {
                return
            }
        }

        oldActions := value.(*[]func())

        // fail
        // freshActions := append(*oldActions, action)

        // success
        freshActions := make([]func(), len(*oldActions)+1)
        copy(freshActions, *oldActions)
        freshActions[len(*oldActions)] = action

        if group.store.CompareAndSwap(key, oldActions, &freshActions) {
            return
        }
    }
}


I tried to use sync.Map + CompareAndSwap to achieve lock-free concurrency slice append, but failed.
I noticed that record 'n' appears repeatedly, but I don't understand why.
Go Playground
func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < syncCount; i++ {
        n := i
        syncSum += n
        action := func() {
            asyncCount += 1
            asyncSum += n
            record[n] += 1
        }

        // actions.Add(key, action)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            actions.Add(key, action)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    actions.Exec(key)

    fmt.Println("count is concurrency safe?", syncCount == asyncCount)
    fmt.Println("  sum is concurrency safe?", syncSum == asyncSum)
}

type Actions struct {
    store sync.Map // key:value = key:*[]func()
}

func (group *Actions) Add(key string, action func()) {
    for {
        value, loaded := group.store.Load(key)
        if !loaded {
            actions := []func(){action}
            value, loaded = group.store.LoadOrStore(key, &actions)
            if !loaded {
                return
            }
        }

        oldActions := value.(*[]func())
        freshActions := append(*oldActions, action)
        if group.store.CompareAndSwap(key, oldActions, &freshActions) {
            return
        }
    }
}

I expect result is
count is concurrency safe? true
  sum is concurrency safe? true

but actual result is
count is concurrency safe? true
  sum is concurrency safe? false


Please make the example complete and runnable as it's currently missing details. Also, what do you mean by using sync.Map for "lock-free" appends? sync.Map uses a mutex internally.

You can't implement append using only a compare and swap, because append does more than simply assign a value. It also requires allocation and copying of N values.

simply checking the count values does not guarantee something is "concurrency safe", you have a data race in your code.

I solved the problem. Thank you for your reminders and assistance.
